# Class 'phpseclib\Crypt\Common\BlockCipher' not found using Phpseclib versions 2 and 3 on WAMP PHP 7.3

Tags: php, phpseclib

Receiving Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'phpseclib\Crypt\Common\BlockCipher' not found in C:\wamp64\www\chuckles.net\oldencrypt\phpseclib\Crypt\Rijndael.php on line 71
1 0.0002 403520 {main}(  ) ...\example2.php:0
2 0.0008 405344 include( 'C:\wamp64\www\chuckles.net\oldencrypt\phpseclib\Crypt\Rijndael.php' ) ...\example2.php:9

```
phpseclib3\Crypt\Rijndael.php line  71 is: 
    class Rijndael extends BlockCipher
    {
        /**
         * The mcrypt specific name of the cipher
         *
         * Mcrypt is useable for 128/192/256-bit $block_size/$key_length. For 160/224 not.
         * \phpseclib3\Crypt\Rijndael determines automatically whether mcrypt is useable
         * or not for the current $block_size/$key_length.
         * In case of, $cipher_name_mcrypt will be set dynamically at run time accordingly.
         *
         * @see \phpseclib3\Crypt\Common\SymmetricKey::cipher_name_mcrypt
         * @see \phpseclib3\Crypt\Common\SymmetricKey::engine
         * @see self::isValidEngine()
         * @var string
         * @access private
         */
```

Actual Script:

```
 <?php 
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib');
    //include "phpseclib/autoload.php";
    include "phpseclib/bootstrap.php";
    include('phpseclib/Crypt/Rijndael.php');
    include('phpseclib/Crypt/Random.php');
    use phpseclib\Crypt\Rijndael as Crypt_Rijndael;
    $text = '57F0-ECD3-1A3B-341E-BA39-F81B-F020-0DE0';
    $secret = 'lkirwf897+22#bbtrm8814z5qq=498j5';
    $iv = '741952hheeyy66#cs!9hjv887mxx7@8y';
    
    echo $text;
    echo encrypt128($secret, $iv, $text);
    echo "\n";
    
    $text = encryptRJ256($secret, $iv, $text);
    echo $text;
    echo "\n";
    echo decryptRJ256($secret, $iv, $text);
    
    function encrypt128($secret, $iv, $str)
    { 
        return base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $secret, $str, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));
    }
    
    function encryptRJ256($key,$iv,$text)
    {
        $cipher = new Crypt_Rijndael('cbc'); 
        $cipher->setBlockLength(256);
        // keys are null-padded to the closest valid size
        // longer than the longest key and it's truncated
        $cipher->setKeyLength(256);
        $cipher->setKey($key);
        // the IV defaults to all-NULLs if not explicitly defined
        $cipher->setIV($iv);
        $cipher->disablePadding();
        $length = strlen($text);
        $pad = 32 - ($length % 32);
        $text = str_pad($text, $length + $pad, chr(0));
        return base64_encode($cipher->encrypt($text));
    }
    function decryptRJ256($key,$iv,$text)
    {
        $cipher = new Crypt_Rijndael('cbc'); // could use CRYPT_RIJNDAEL_MODE_CBC
        $cipher->setBlockLength(256);
        // keys are null-padded to the closest valid size
        // longer than the longest key and it's truncated
        $cipher->setKeyLength(256);
        $cipher->setKey($key);
        // the IV defaults to all-NULLs if not explicitly defined
        $cipher->setIV($iv);
        $cipher->disablePadding();
        return $cipher->decrypt(base64_decode($text)); 
    }
```

Comment: In the above code snippet, 'phpseclib3' is shown and should be 'phpseclib'. I copied that code snippet to notepad before i again ran the test with everything in 'phpseclib' .The error is generated regardless of the name of phpseclib.

Comment: This is why you want to use an autoloader such as Composer; the alternative is dozens of lines of `include_once` in your PHP. The class is trying to extend `BlockCipher` but the source for that class hasn't been loaded.

Comment: Thank you, i'll do it.